# Connecting to local instance of Mongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to connect to a local instance of MongoDB in Python, using the following connection. The version (commented out line) with connection to cloud works perfectly, however the localhost line with 27017 fails to get the list of attributes from database. What could the problem be?

```
#mongo_url = "mongodb+srv://admin:mypassword@cluster0.l2vfs.mongodb.net/MYDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority" #WORKS
mongo_url = "mongodb://admin:mypassword@localhost:27017/MYDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority" #FAILS
client = MongoClient(mongo_url)

database = client["MYDB"]
date_price_collection = database["historical_prices"]


def gettickers(attribute_name):
    try:
        cursor = date_price_collection.find({},{attribute_name: 1})
        list_of_tickers = []
        for document in cursor:
            list_of_tickers.append(document[attribute_name])
        return list_of_tickers
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error: could not retrieve from Mongo")
        return ""

print(gettickers("ticker"))
```

Grateful for any help

Comment: You would really need to show us your code (both the code that works and the code that fails).

Comment: sure, have added to clarify

Comment: this works for me:
local_mongo_url=mongodb://localhost:27017/DBNAME?readPreference=primary&ssl=false

Comment: thank you! It seems to connect now and get a cursor but still unable to actually retrive any values..